# Connect to Express over Extreme

Tags: airport

I have an Airport Extreme as my main router in my house and have recently bought an Airport Express to use as an extender.

This is all now set up and working fine, with the Express bouncing on the internet connection for me to use throughout the house. However sometimes my phone will connect to the Express instead of the Extreme, although the Extreme is closer. Is there a way to selectively choose which router to connect to? The problem is that there is a limit to the number of devices that can connect to the Express, and this limit is being reached every now and then.

Comment: Typically the choice is made by which one gives off the stronger signal.  There's no way to choose unless you create two separate wireless networks.  Actually I suppose you could dive into config files and give one priority based on its MAC address, but as far as I know that would be difficult and probably not worthwhile.  How many devices do you think can connect to an Extreme?  I've never seen an Extreme stop working due to too many connections.

Comment: @Harv is right - we have airport extremes that often get upward of 40 devices in everyday use with no problems at all.

Comment: The issue isn't how many devices connect to the extreme, it's how many connect to the express. More than about 10 and it is unstable.

Comment: Have you tried using WDS?

Comment: Is it possible to limit access to the Extreme by MAC address and allow a wider range of devices to use the Express?

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this (like they said in the comments) would be to enable allowed Access control and specifying which devices are allowed to access the express. This is an easy solution if your device's are not going to change a lot :)